# Random Blink LEDs

Tags: arduino-nano, rgb-led

How can I make LEDs blink randomly?

I found a piece of code, but it is not working for me. I probably need something other than `setPixel()`, but I don't know what.

I am using the [Fast.Led library](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED) with Arduino Nano and WS2812B LEDs

```c
void loop() {
    Twinkle(CRGB::Red, 10, 100, false);
}

void Twinkle(uint32_t color, uint16_t Count, uint16_t SpeedDelay, boolean OnlyOne) 
{
    FastLED.setBrightness(MAX_BRIGHTNESS);
    fill_solid(leds, random(NUM_LEDS), CRGB::White);
    FastLED.show(); 
    for (int i=0; i < Count; i++) {
//        setPixel(random(NUM_LEDS),red,green,blue);  //!ORIGINAL LINE OF CODE!
        setPixel(random(NUM_LEDS), color);  //!MY LINE! 
        FastLED.show();
        delay(SpeedDelay);
        if (OnlyOne) {
            fill_solid(leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB::Black);
            FastLED.show();
        }
    }

    delay(SpeedDelay);
    return;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `setPixel()`? Does the original code work at all? Remove the statements within exclamation marks and use proper comments for your code. A link to your library would also be nice.

Comment: `it is not working for me` - what *is* it doing? Nothing blinks? Too many things blink? It isn't random? Aliens kidnap you and do scientific experiments on you? "Not working" doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly whats not working with your code,it would be really helpful if you elaborate more. 
But here is some code that I wrote and I think it will get the job done:

```
//declare our variables:
int myPins[] = {2, 4, 8, 3, 6}; //Enter the number of the pins being used
int RNum = 0;

void loop()
{
    DigitalWrite(myPins[RNum],LOW);
    RNum = Random(0,MAX) // MAX being the number of LEDs connected minus one 
    //the above generates a random number
    DigitalWrite(myPins[RNum],High);
}
```

This will turn on one LED at a time.